# How to prevent words containing certain letters from being echoed out in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, directory, echo, glob

What happens here is that all the files in the directory are retrieved and then echoed out onto the page through PHP. The files contained in `$blacklist` are the ones that are not echoed out.

However, how could I change this so that if the file name (that is to be echoed out) contains the letters `.txt` all together in a row at the end of the word, it is then put into the blacklist so that it's not echoed out.

Does this make any sense?

```
<?php

    $blacklist = array("one.jps", "two.txt", "four.html" , ".txt");
    $files = array_diff(glob("*.*"), $blacklist);

    foreach($files as $file)
        echo "<div class='post'><a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?file=" . $file . "'><p>" . $file . "</p></a></div>";


    if(!empty($_GET["file"]) && !in_array($_GET["file"], $blacklist) && file_exists($_GET["file"])) 
        $thesource = htmlentities(file_get_contents($_GET["file"]));

?>
```

Comment: apart from the problem you are facing, your code is open to a variety of serious security risks.... file_get_contents($_GET["file"]) is extremely dangerous...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep `$blacklist` for further usage:

```
$blacklist = preg_grep("/\b.txt\b/", $files);

foreach (array_diff($files, $blacklist) as $whiteListedFile) {

    // do your things
}
```

[preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) is what you need here. Keep in mind that the example above will blacklists "file.txt" but **not** "file.txts" or "file.stxt" . Adjust the pattern for your needs. [This](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) is a good online regex tester for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. Haven't played with the syntax, so you will have to work on that.

```
preg_match('.txt', $string)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: You are correct, but I didn't want to do all the work for the OP.  Just point him in the right direction.